Flutter not working after installing shared_preferences
After installing shared_preferences, my app is not working.
Im getting this error:
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\tobik\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
`

When i run flutter clean and flutter pub get without including the shared preferences everything is working.
I have tried updating android studio on Windows 11.
How do i make it work? Im using visual studio code.

this error has many reason, i suggest u to run "flutter pub outdated" in ur VS-terminal to upgrade ur 3rd party packages version & try to use older "share preference" version

I get this when running the "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions" and nothing changes. I also noticed the app is working on chrome emulator but not on android emulator.

First of all, I suggest opening the "android" folder of your Flutter project with Android Studio to build the right version of Gradle. It will assure us that there is no conflict according to your Gradle version and the android SDK and also the flutter version. After that if the problem exists we can move to the next step.

Thank you so much. After opening the "android" folder in android studio when running the project it was saying to add " ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973" to build.gradle in "app" folder at now it is working. Would you know what to do so it works correctly after normally creating flutter project?

I encountered this issue after upgrading to Android Studio Ladybug. To resolve it, I updated the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) dependency from 8.1.0 to 8.7.2. Make sure to follow the pre-upgrade steps before changing the version and run the post-upgrade steps afterward.

Provide more info, links and ideally explain why the above is needed. Also provide info when it comes to the part "...follow the pre-upgrade steps before changing the version and run the post-upgrade steps..."

I resolved the issue by changes:

change(or add) to android/settings.gradle:
id "com.android.application" version "8.7.0" apply false
add to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip
install Android NDK (if not installed): 

